# ion-checkbox:checked not working angular 2 ionic 2

Tags: css, angular, checkbox, ionic2, ionic3

I want to execute css when ion-checkbox is checked. But ion-checkbox:checked doesnt execute.[image: Image1]

I want to highlight all column below it.

Here's what I've done.

**Html file

```
<ion-row class = "DefaultBundle">
    <ion-col col-4>Description of Services</ion-col>
    <ion-item col-4 style = "background-color: #84AEF9 !important;">
        <ion-label class = "Services">Full Service Agency</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox class = "Bundle1"></ion-checkbox> // <-- Here's the check box
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item col-4 [hidden] = "!DefaultBundle.checked" style = "background-color: #84AEF9 !important;">
        <ion-label class = "Services">Frost & Co Lite</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox class = "Bundle2"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

Here are some of the fields that I want to highlight.

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col>Market Appraisal</ion-col>
    <ion-col><ion-checkbox disabled checked></ion-checkbox></ion-col>
    <ion-col [hidden] = "!DefaultBundle.checked"><ion-checkbox disabled checked></ion-checkbox></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col>For Sale Board</ion-col>
    <ion-col><ion-checkbox disabled checked></ion-checkbox></ion-col>
    <ion-col [hidden] = "!DefaultBundle.checked"><ion-checkbox disabled checked></ion-checkbox></ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col>Rightmove Portal Listing</ion-col>
    <ion-col><ion-checkbox disabled checked></ion-checkbox></ion-col>
    <ion-col [hidden] = "!DefaultBundle.checked"><ion-checkbox disabled checked></ion-checkbox></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Here's my CSS.

```
.Bundle1:checked
{
    background-color: red; // <-- this is just for testing. And it never executes.
}
```

**Question:** What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming `ion-checkbox` to be like a simple `input` of type `checkbox/radio` or `option`.

:checked [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

> The :checked CSS pseudo-class selector represents any radio (), checkbox (), or option ( in a ) element that is checked or toggled to an on state.

If you glance at the [`ion-checkbox`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/checkbox/checkbox.ts) component code,

> ```
> '<div class="checkbox-icon" [class.checkbox-checked]="_value">' +
>       '<div class="checkbox-inner"></div>' +
>     '</div>' +
>     '<button role="checkbox" ' +
>             'type="button" ' +
>             'ion-button="item-cover" ' +
>             '[id]="id" ' +
>             '[attr.aria-checked]="_value" ' +
>             '[attr.aria-labelledby]="_labelId" ' +
>             '[attr.aria-disabled]="_disabled" ' +
>             'class="item-cover"> ' +
>     '</button>',
> ```

It is a **button** when it is shown.

You will need to create a custom class

```
  .isChecked{
     background-color: red;
  }
```

And set it using `[class]` dynamically based on a boolean value.

```
 <ion-checkbox [class.isChecked] = "isCurrentCheckboxChecked"></ion-checkbox>
```

Comment: Well thanks, this help me a lot. But my question is I want to highlight all the fields below it.
`.Bundle1:checked
{
    background-color: red; // <-- this is just for testing.
}`

Comment: you will have to create another class and toggle with a boolean variable as I explained.. Doesnt that work?